# Cannot run a python script in a Linux terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib, terminal

I am running a rocky9 Linux terminal and trying to download/clone a git repo. This works, but when trying to plot a graph using the following python script, nothing happens. It works fine on Windows, but the graph does not pop up or display in the terminal.

Heres the Py script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create a dictionary of data from a file in csv format
def createData(filename):
    data = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split(',')
            data[int(key)] = int(val)
    return data

def plotData(data):
    x = []
    y = []
    for key in data:
        x.append(key)
        y.append(data[key])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show(block=True)

plots = createData('graphPlots.txt')
plotData(plots)
```

The graphPlots.txt file is indeed in the same dir and has the following contents:

```
2,2400
3,2900
4,2800
5,4300
6,8100
7,20300
8,28400
9,41000
10,31600
11,34900
12,52700
13,58200
14,69600
15,85400
16,131200
17,124900
.....
```

This does change due to another Java file running, but I think the Python script is the issue. Any help is appreciated.

I found a similar solution stating I needed to add the "block=True" parameter to the plt.show. I tried this but this didn't work either.

Comment: If you do `print(plots)` do you see the output?

Comment: It's very uncommon to store two paired _sequences_ into a dictionary,  it's more common to store two paired sequences in, ehm, two sequences. Do you have any reasons to do the dictionary stuff?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I executed your script and it worked perfectly fine, with `block=True` and also without it. For this reason I am going to vote for closing your question as it is "not reproducible"

Comment: @gboffi interesting. Just to confirm, this displayed a graph in the terminal on Linux?

Comment: Yes, your script worked perfectly on Linux.